# Ember Data - Bring data to template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Can't access my requested Data (from REST API) from the template.
 For example to get a name or something like that, tried something with

```
{{model}} or {{App.Customer.name}}
```

But didn't worked.

JSON from API:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "name": "Omegasoft"
  }
}
```

app.js Code:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('customer');
  }
});

App.ApplicationAdapter= DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/rest'
});

App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is with how you represent the data in your JSON API. Ember-data is expecting you to follow their naming conventions. So if you have a `customer` model, the JSON you send to your app should look like this:

```
{
    'customers': [{
        'name': 'Omegasoft'
    }]
}
```

In the template, as long as the model is linked, you should be able to just put `{{name}}` in the template and Ember will be smart enough to link them.

If the template is getting sent an array, you'll also have to use `{{#each}}` to iterate through each object.

I don't know if there are potentially other problems in your code as well.

Comment: What did you mean with 'the model is linked' ? Thanks for your first advise

Comment: Basically, specifying a model in the route should link it, assuming that everything is named properly.

Comment: Ok, it works now thanks. But do I really have to wrap it with ((#each)) every time ?

Comment: Only if an array is being sent to your template. If you have something like `return this.get('store').find('customer', params.customer_id)`, you should be able to exclude the `#each` helper.